# Bouncycastle pgp decryption correct size but all blank

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

When I call this, it successfully encrypts my string but the output of the decrypted text is blank.  I get no errors and the byteArray of the output string is of the correct lenth (102), however it's just 102 zeros.  This is adapted from the KeyBasedFileProcessor example but is attempting to be stream/string based instead of file based.

```
package com.common.security.pgp;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPOnePassSignatureList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;

/**
 * A simple utility class that encrypts/decrypts public key based encryption
 * files.
 * <p>
 * To encrypt a file: KeyBasedFileProcessor -e [-a|-ai] fileName publicKeyFile.<br>
 * If -a is specified the output file will be "ascii-armored". If -i is
 * specified the output file will be have integrity checking added.
 * <p>
 * To decrypt: KeyBasedFileProcessor -d fileName secretKeyFile passPhrase.
 * <p>
 * Note 1: this example will silently overwrite files, nor does it pay any
 * attention to the specification of "_CONSOLE" in the filename. It also expects
 * that a single pass phrase will have been used.
 * <p>
 * Note 2: if an empty file name has been specified in the literal data object
 * contained in the encrypted packet a file with the name filename.out will be
 * generated in the current working directory.
 */
public class PgpEncryption3 {
    /**
     * A simple routine that opens a key ring file and loads the first available
     * key suitable for encryption.
     * 
     * @param in
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws PGPException
     */
    private static PGPPublicKey readPublicKey(InputStream in)
            throws IOException, PGPException {
        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(in);

        //
        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for
        // encryption, in the real
        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
        //

        //
        // iterate through the key rings.
        //
        Iterator rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings();

        while (rIt.hasNext()) {
            PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) rIt.next();
            Iterator kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();

            while (kIt.hasNext()) {
                PGPPublicKey k = (PGPPublicKey) kIt.next();

                if (k.isEncryptionKey()) {
                    return k;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
    }

    /**
     * Search a secret key ring collection for a secret key corresponding to
     * keyID if it exists.
     * 
     * @param pgpSec
     *            a secret key ring collection.
     * @param keyID
     *            keyID we want.
     * @param pass
     *            passphrase to decrypt secret key with.
     * @return
     * @throws PGPException
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     */
    private static PGPPrivateKey findSecretKey(
            PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec, long keyID, char[] pass)
            throws PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
        PGPSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.getSecretKey(keyID);

        if (pgpSecKey == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey(pass, "BC");
    }

    /**
     * decrypt the passed in message stream
     */
    private static void decryptFile(InputStream in, InputStream keyIn,
            char[] passwd, String defaultFileName, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);


        try {
            PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
            PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

            Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
            //
            // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
            //
            if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
                enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
            } else {
                enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
            }

            //
            // find the secret key
            //
            Iterator it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
            PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
            PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
            PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(
                    PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));

            while (sKey == null && it.hasNext()) {
                pbe = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) it.next();

                sKey = findSecretKey(pgpSec, pbe.getKeyID(), passwd);
            }

            if (sKey == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "secret key for message not found.");
            }

            InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(sKey, "BC");

            PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);

            Object message = plainFact.nextObject();

            if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
                PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
                PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData
                        .getDataStream());

                message = pgpFact.nextObject();
            }

            if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
                System.out.println(message);
                PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) message;
                System.out.println(ld.getFileName());
                System.out.println(ld.getDataStream());
                InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0) {
                    System.out.println(ch);
                    out.write(ch);
                }
            } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
                throw new PGPException(
                        "encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
            } else {
                throw new PGPException(
                        "message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
            }

            if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected()) {
                if (!pbe.verify()) {
                    System.err.println("message failed integrity check");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("message integrity check passed");
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("no message integrity check");
            }
        } catch (PGPException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            if (e.getUnderlyingException() != null) {
                e.getUnderlyingException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void writeStreamToLiteralData(OutputStream out,
            char fileType, byte[] data, String fileName, Date modDate) throws IOException {
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();
        OutputStream pOut = lData.open(out, fileType, fileName, data.length, modDate);

        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            pOut.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        lData.close();
        in.close();
    }

    private static void encryptFile(OutputStream out, byte[] data,String fileName,
            PGPPublicKey encKey, boolean armor, boolean withIntegrityCheck, Date modDate)
            throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException {
        if (armor) {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();




            writeStreamToLiteralData(bOut,PGPLiteralData.TEXT, data, fileName,modDate);


            PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                    PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, withIntegrityCheck,
                    new SecureRandom(), "BC");

            cPk.addMethod(encKey);

            byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();

            OutputStream cOut = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);

            cOut.write(bytes);

            cOut.close();

            out.close();
        } catch (PGPException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            if (e.getUnderlyingException() != null) {
                e.getUnderlyingException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());


        Date modDate = new Date();

        String dataToEncrypt = "THIS IS SOME TEXTTHIS IS SOME TEXTTHIS IS SOME TEXTTHIS IS SOME TEXTTHIS IS SOME TEXTTHIS IS SOME TEXT";
        System.out.println(dataToEncrypt.length());
        byte[] data = dataToEncrypt.getBytes();
        String fileName = "blah.txt";
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        FileInputStream pKeyIn = new FileInputStream("/Users/me/blah.pub.key");
        encryptFile(out, data, fileName,readPublicKey(pKeyIn), true, false,modDate);
        System.out.println(new String(out.toByteArray()));

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(in);
        FileInputStream sKeyIn = new FileInputStream("/Users/me/blah.sec.key");
        ByteArrayOutputStream decOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        decryptFile(in, sKeyIn, "mypass".toCharArray(), "blah.txt", decOut);
        System.out.println(decOut.toByteArray().length);
        System.out.println(new String(decOut.toByteArray()));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full working example

```
package com.common.security.pgp;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;

/**
 * Simple routine to encrypt and decrypt using a Public and Private key with passphrase. This service
 * routine provides the basic PGP services between byte arrays.
 * 
 */
public class PgpEncryption {


    private static PGPPrivateKey findSecretKey(
            PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec, long keyID, char[] pass)
            throws PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
        PGPSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.getSecretKey(keyID);

        if (pgpSecKey == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey(pass, "BC");
    }

    /**
     * decrypt the passed in message stream
     * 
     * @param encrypted
     *            The message to be decrypted.
     * @param passPhrase
     *            Pass phrase (key)
     * 
     * @return Clear text as a byte array. I18N considerations are not handled
     *         by this routine
     * @exception IOException
     * @exception PGPException
     * @exception NoSuchProviderException
     */
    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrypted, InputStream keyIn, char[] password)
            throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(encrypted);

        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc = null;
        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();

        //
        // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
        //
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        } else {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }



        //
        // find the secret key
        //
        Iterator it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
        PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
        PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(
                PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));

        while (sKey == null && it.hasNext()) {
            pbe = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) it.next();

            sKey = findSecretKey(pgpSec, pbe.getKeyID(), password);
        }

        if (sKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "secret key for message not found.");
        }

        InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(sKey, "BC");



        PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);

        PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) pgpFact.nextObject();

        pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());

        PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) pgpFact.nextObject();

        InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int ch;

        while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0) {
            out.write(ch);

        }

        byte[] returnBytes = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();
        return returnBytes;
    }

    /**
     * Simple PGP encryptor between byte[].
     * 
     * @param clearData
     *            The test to be encrypted
     * @param passPhrase
     *            The pass phrase (key). This method assumes that the key is a
     *            simple pass phrase, and does not yet support RSA or more
     *            sophisiticated keying.
     * @param fileName
     *            File name. This is used in the Literal Data Packet (tag 11)
     *            which is really inly important if the data is to be related to
     *            a file to be recovered later. Because this routine does not
     *            know the source of the information, the caller can set
     *            something here for file name use that will be carried. If this
     *            routine is being used to encrypt SOAP MIME bodies, for
     *            example, use the file name from the MIME type, if applicable.
     *            Or anything else appropriate.
     * 
     * @param armor
     * 
     * @return encrypted data.
     * @exception IOException
     * @exception PGPException
     * @exception NoSuchProviderException
     */
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] clearData, PGPPublicKey encKey,
            String fileName,boolean withIntegrityCheck, boolean armor)
            throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
        if (fileName == null) {
            fileName = PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE;
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        OutputStream out = encOut;
        if (armor) {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
                PGPCompressedDataGenerator.ZIP);
        OutputStream cos = comData.open(bOut); // open it with the final
        // destination
        PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();

        // we want to generate compressed data. This might be a user option
        // later,
        // in which case we would pass in bOut.
        OutputStream pOut = lData.open(cos, // the compressed output stream
                PGPLiteralData.BINARY, fileName, // "filename" to store
                clearData.length, // length of clear data
                new Date() // current time
                );
        pOut.write(clearData);

        lData.close();
        comData.close();

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(
                PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom(),
                "BC");

        cPk.addMethod(encKey);

        byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();

        OutputStream cOut = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);

        cOut.write(bytes); // obtain the actual bytes from the compressed stream

        cOut.close();

        out.close();

        return encOut.toByteArray();
    }

    private static PGPPublicKey readPublicKey(InputStream in)
            throws IOException, PGPException {
        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(in);

        //
        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for
        // encryption, in the real
        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
        //

        //
        // iterate through the key rings.
        //
        Iterator rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings();

        while (rIt.hasNext()) {
            PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) rIt.next();
            Iterator kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();

            while (kIt.hasNext()) {
                PGPPublicKey k = (PGPPublicKey) kIt.next();

                if (k.isEncryptionKey()) {
                    return k;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());


        byte[] original = "Hello world".getBytes();
        System.out.println("Starting PGP test");

        FileInputStream pubKey = new FileInputStream("/Users/me/pub.key");
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(original, readPublicKey(pubKey), null,
                true, true);

        FileOutputStream dfis = new FileOutputStream("/Users/me/enc.asc");
        dfis.write(encrypted);
        dfis.close();

        byte[] encFromFile = getBytesFromFile(new File("/Users/me/enc.asc"));
        FileInputStream secKey = new FileInputStream("/Users/me/sec.key");

        System.out.println("\nencrypted data = '" + new String(encrypted) + "'");

        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(encFromFile, secKey, "passphrase".toCharArray());

        System.out.println("\ndecrypted data = '" + new String(decrypted) + "'");


    }
}
```

Comment: @Rocky4Ever No idea, I wrote this 10 years ago.